# Next auth protecting all routes with middleware

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to protect all routes in my next app from unauthenticated users and redirect them to the "/auth" route.

Versions that I'm using:
"next": "13.2.3",
"next-auth": "^4.20.1",

I want to use middleware for this purpose, so I placed middleware.js file in the root of my project with the next code:

```
export { default } from 'next-auth/middleware';

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!/auth))'],
    pages: {
        signIn: '/auth',
    },
};
```

But it doesn't work. It redirects users to "/auth" route only from the "/" route, but any other route is still unprotected including /api routes.

Could you help me to find a mistake?